# automatically login to old site when a user logged into new site

Tags: php, drupal

I have 2 sites, one is in drupal other is just PHP, when somebody visits drupal after logged into the PHP, he should be automatically logged into the drupal site

Is is possible ? both db is in same server

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, what you want is the same cookie used by both of your applications. Several options here:

1. **Create a Drupal compatible cookie by hand.** Remember that the cookie domain and a lot of other options must be exactly the same for Drupal to remember it.
2. **Use the Drupal login API, if accessible.** By using those methods to authenticate someone, you ensure that it's the same user that is also present in the Drupal system. This way you would have to look at what's going on in the Drupal API and use it the same way.
3. Best approch in my opinion: **Use a system that is designed for single sing on methods**, like Google Accounts, Facebook Account or any other OAuth library. Drawback here would be the change of look&feel of your existing application since it has to be adjusted so the external accounts match the internal accounts (not quite sure, how this is handled since I've never implemented a OAuth system)

Oh and by *cookie* I mean: Any token that is recognized by Drupal as a login session, can be a real cookie file, some database entry, both, I don't know - you will have to look at the source code there and do some reverse engineering.